# Pythonic way to merge two List of tuples into single list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

Hi I'm pretty new to Python, so I'm not really aware of all the little tricks and shortcuts yet.  I have two multi-dimensional arrays:

```
>>> colorStrings
[('0', '2371_9890_020'), ('1', '2371_9031_100'), ('2', '2371_9890_464')]
```

and

```
>>> skus
[('0', '0017651670'), ('0', '0017651688'), ('0', '0017651696'), ('0', '0017651704'), ('0', '0017651712'), ('0', '0017651720'), ('0', '0017651738'), ('1', '0017650896'), ('1', '0017650904'), ('1', '0017650912'), ('1', '0017650920'), ('1', '0017650938'), ('1', '0017650946'), ('1', '0017650953'), ('2', '0017651746'), ('2', '0017651753'), ('2', '0017651761'), ('2', '0017651779'), ('2', '0017651787'), ('2', '0017651795'), ('2', '0017651803')]
```

Basically, I want to merge these into an array of dictionary objects.  Something like:

```
[
{
   'colorString': '2371_9890_020'
   'skus': ('0017651670', '0017651688', '0017651696', '0017651704', '0017651712', '0017651720, '0017651738')
},

{
   'colorString': '2371_9031_100'
   'skus': ('0017650896', '0017650904', '0017650912', '0017650920', '0017650938', '0017650946, '0017650953')
},

{
   'colorString': '2371_9890_464'
   'skus': ('0017651746', '0017651753', '0017651761', '0017651779', '0017651787', '0017651795, '0017651803')
}
]
```

Is there some kewl Pythonic way of doing this really easily using Lamba expressions or some niftiness?  Thanks!

Comment: groupby from module itertools  can also help !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this :

```
 result = [
     {
         'colorString' : color, 
         'skus' : [value for key, value in skus if key is colorkey]
     } for colorkey, color in colorStrings 
 ]
```

Comment: Decided to mark this as the answer just cuz I like it..  Though the defauldict() method works quite nicely as well..

Comment: This is potentially quite inefficient, as it has to iterate over `colorKey` everytime for every entry in colorStrings

Comment: Yea I noticed that as well - however, both my lists will always be quite small..  Probably under 10 items each.  And this code isn't perf critical..

Answer (score 9):

Use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group the skus by sku_id first, then use a list comprehension to generate the combined dataset

```
from collections import defaultdict

sku_dict = defaultdict(list)
for color_id, sku in skus:
    sku_dict[color_id].append(sku)

combined = [dict(colorString=color, skus=sku_dict.get(color_id)) for color_id, color in colorStrings]
```

Comment: Well that works perfectly - now to figure out why it works :)